# How to access my custom UIPresentationController from within presented controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uipresentationcontroller

This is how I perform transitioning:

```
extension UIViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    public func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return OverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }

    func presentOverlayController(_ controller: UIViewController) {

        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        controller.transitioningDelegate = self

        present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And then within my presented controller (`AlertVC`) at some point I need to access its presentation controller:

```
print(presentationController as? OverlayPresentationController) //nil
print(presentationController) //is ok, UIPresentationController
```

Why?

Presenting:

```
let controller = AlertVC.instantiate()
controller.update()
presentOverlayController(controller)

class AlertVC: UIViewController {

    class func instantiate() -> AlertVC {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Alert", bundle: Bundle(for: LoginVC.classForCoder())).instantiateInitialViewController() as! AlertVC
    }

    func update() {
        _ = view

        print(presentationController as? OverlayPresentationController) //nil
    }
}
```

Comment: UIPresentationController has a property named containerView. It holds the view hierarchy of the presentation and presented controllers

Comment: Sounds promising... is it possible to access my presentation controller this way?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about that , I have read it over internet so i share it with you , you may try if works then your lot's of time will be saved . Good luck

Answer (score -3):

You get the view controller that is presenting the current view controller by calling presentingViewController

```
// The view controller that presented this view controller (or its farthest ancestor.)
self.presentingViewController
```

If your presenting view controller is in a navigation controller that returns a UINavigationController. You can get the view controller you need like so:

```
let presentingNVC = self.presentingViewController as? UINavigationViewController
let neededVC = presentingNVC.viewControllers.last as? NeededViewController
```

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Where did you try to call `presentingViewController` ? If you try to call it in `viewDidLoad:` it is possible that the value is not set yet.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk and are you sure you are calling it in the view controller that you present using `present(controller, animated: true)`?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I think you are missing `presentationController.delegate = self` above the return statement in `presentationController(forPresented:presenting:source:)`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Can you add your init code to the question?